# Mancala game in Java - using int array in while loop

Tags: java, arrays, junit, while-loop

I am working on a Mancala game project. In case you are interested in the GUI, here it is:

https://s32.postimg.org/hxzmhxt1x/mancala.png

I am working on a method that will cause the computer player to select the pit closest to their store that will allow it to capture stones from the human player. A capture is made when the last stone lands in an empty pit directly across from a pit with stones on the other side. I am including the relevant method below. The parameter "theBoard" is an int array to represent all of the pits including the stores and how many stones are contained in each pit of the array. Here is the code I have for the method:

```
public int selectPit(int[] theBoard) {
        int pitChoice = theBoard.length - 2;        

        while (pitChoice >= theBoard.length / 2) {
            int destinationPit = theBoard[pitChoice] + pitChoice;
            int opposite = (theBoard.length - 2) - destinationPit;
            if (theBoard[destinationPit] == 0 && theBoard[opposite] > 0 && destinationPit <= (theBoard.length - 2) && destinationPit > (theBoard.length / 2)) {
                return pitChoice;
            } else {
                pitChoice--;
            }
        }
        return this.selectClosestPitWithStones(theBoard);
    }
```

The last line that calls the selectClosestPitWithStones is a call to a backup method just in case there are no options that would allow a capture. The functionality of this backup method works as intended. However, my selectPit method keeps returning incorrect results or "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1".

I am using JUnit tests that are correctly written to test this method. Here is one such test:

```
@Test
    public void testCapturePit0() {
        this.setUp();
        int[] theBoard = {6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0};
        assertEquals(4, this.strategy.selectPit(theBoard));
    }
```

Any ideas on what could be causing incorrect results?

Comment: What's causing the incorrect results?  A logic error.  Use a debugger or output some debugging System.out.println() statements.  This is part of programming.

Comment: You're moving outside the bounds of the array in your while loop. You'll have to debug its iterations to discover why. It's perfectly feasible for this error to occur based on the values involved. Think carefully on your algorithm and write smaller lines of code, outputting values to System.out as necessary, until it's the way you require it to be. And test it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug it and verify that variables have the values you expect.

The problem at the moment is one of the variables going out of the bounds of the array. Remember that array indexes go from 0 to length minus one. Both `int destinationPit = theBoard[pitChoice] + pitChoice;` and `int destinationPit = theBoard[pitChoice] + pitChoice;` could go out of bounds depending on the input or the state of the array.